# ArcGIS compute nearest network neighbour for each point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, network

I have a set of points and I would like to calculate a value for each point to indicate how 'clustered' to other points that point is.

Distance to nearest neighbour (through a network) would do fine.  Other clustering measures with significance would be good too: but Getis Ord GI and Local Moran's I rely on the points having attribute values, which mine don't.

How can you do this in ArcGIS, produce a measure for each point that tells you something about how clustered that point is, without attribute values?

Comment: do you have network analyst ? you could then use OD cost matrix

Answer (score 1):

Point Distance tool will give you distance from one point to all points in a given search radius. Then you can use the output to see concentreated areas with certain visualization tools such as "Quantities" or cut-off some points by using definition query. If you have a network graph then you can use OD Cost Matrix tool.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this tool: Standard Distance?

![image: toolboxsnapshot]

Comment: I believe it only works on geometric mean center. Question seems to be about a different problem.

Comment: I gave the best answer I could find to an ambiguous question. How "clustered" something is can certainly be determined by analyzing its STDV from a mean center.